# BIOS does not show all installed ram

Tags: windows, memory, bios, cpu-z

I've installed an additional ram module on my laptop which makes it 12GB in total (one 8GB Stick and one 4 GB stick).
But my bios shows only 8GB.
When I check with CPU-Z it shows only my 4GB module in the SPD tab and 8GB memory in the Memory tab.
CPU-z tells me that my 4GB module is in the first slot but windows says 8GB module is in the first slot.
I don't know what to do.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your motherboard is single-channel, either via a setting that can be edited by you, or was manufactured that way, in which case you can't do much about it. What's the exact make and model of your mobo? Plus, can you go into BIOS/UEFI and check if you can set your RAM frequency manually? There's a slight discrepancy in RAM clocks speeds, between your two sticks.

Comment: Just to make sure: The other "Slots" on the SPD tab are empty?

Comment: @Robert yeah they all are empty

Comment: Please post the exact module name of the 8GB module (manufacturer plus complete product name including all numbers and characters).

Comment: @Robert I don't know about that, CPUz does not show anything about 8GB module.

Comment: @Robert I guess the only information it gives is in the third picture

Comment: Knowing the brand, model and CPU on your motherboard would help too, but I strongly suspect your mobo doesn't support dual-channel RAM.

Comment: @Robert but why it has two slots for memory?

Comment: It can be for backup RAM, e.g. one stick starts to underperform, but the other picks up the slack, because it's physically present, receives power, and the bus will swtich to it if the first stick malfunctions. It's serial RAM, instead of parallel RAM as in a multi-channel RAM setup. It's either that, or your CPU is old, and of the "ganged" persuasion (no double entendre), and channels your two RAM channels into a single one. Those CPUs are few and far between nowadays, but an old Celeron or AMD Turion would do that, depending on the mobo it's installed on.

Comment: @Robert my cpu is new Core i7 6700HQ

Comment: @Didier - What in the world are you talking about?  The author’s motherboard absolutely supports dual channel memory, now the only question, is if the behavior being exhibited is due to the size difference and the fact it’s currently running in single channel is an entirely different story.

Comment: @HadiMoloofi - Please edit your question and provide the necessary information to answer your question instead of a comment.

Comment: @Ramhound what that information would be?

Comment: You have been asked to provide specific information on the 8 GB module.  An answer to your question cannot be submitted without detailed specifications on that module.

Comment: Given the reluctance of the OP to tell us what brand and model of motherboard he has on his PC, it's hard to tell which is which. I posted my comment about some CPUs being unable to deal with dual-channel RAM *before* he told us what his CPU was, plus we still don't know if he got the mobo at the same time as the CPU, or if he's been going Frankenstein on his spare time. I'm old enough to remember some lines of CPU that *couldn't* handle multi-channel RAM, even though they were installed with multi-slot mobos. OEMs did that a lot, back in the day, because it was cheaper.